# using write() function in C/C++ on Linux to write 70kB via UART Beaglebone Black

Tags: c++, c, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to write a image via UART on Beaglebone Black. But when I use the `write()` function in library .

```
int  write(int  handle, void *buffer, int nbyte);
```

Regardless of the agurment `nbyte` has `int` type, I can not transfer 70kB at once. I displayed the number of byte which is transfered, and the result is the number of byte = 4111.

```
length = write(fd,body.c_str(),strlen(body.c_str())); // 
cout<<length<<endl; // result length = 4111;
cout<<strlen(body.c_str())<<endl; // result strlen(body.c_str()) = 72255;
```

I hope to hear from you!

Comment: Have you tried writing the leftover data until everything is transmitted?

Comment: If `body` is a `std::string` object, why not use `body.length()` (or `body.size()`) instead of those `strlen`  calls?

Comment: As for your problem, have you considered writing in a loop?

Comment: I want to transfer 70kB at once time and I think nbyte is int, so it must be greater than 4111

Comment: By the way, can the "string" you write contain embedded zeroes (i.e. the *value* zero, not the character `'0'`)? Is it binary data?

Comment: actually, I used encode base64 algorithm before, so my data is character which has char type. and body has string type. both body.size() either strlen(), I think it is ok

Comment: thank you joachim, can you tell me why I can not transfer the data which is greater than 4111, while the type of nbyte is int ?

Comment: Without knowing the exact data it's impossible to say anything for certain. It might be because of buffering somewhere, it might be because of embedded terminators in the string (*try* using `body.size()`), it might be because transmission problems, or something different completely.

Comment: my data like this:
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCEUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAGccAigAYkZCTUQwMTAwMGE5ZTAzMDAwMDBmMTEwMDAwNjkyYjAwMDA4Yj

Comment: I transfered successfully data via internet by using socket. I think my string do not have any problems. Initially, my data was binary and I used base64 encode to convert them to character

Comment: In fact, I have to transfer data via UART to GPRS module and send the data to a webserver, I'm using POST method in HTTP /1.1 protocol, so I have to send all data at once time. It is also the reason why I do not use the loop

Comment: BTW, fundamentally, a UART transfers one byte at a time.  Some may have  a FIFO that you can load.  In either case, you need to *poll* the UART to see if it is empty, then fill it up again.  On some platforms, the UART will interrupt when it is ready to transmit again.  So the question is, where is the loop, in `write` or do you have to do your own loop; you may have to do both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `write` call does not assure that you can write the amount of data supplied, that's why it as an integer as its return, not a Boolean. The behavior you see is actually common among different operating systems, it may be due to the underline device might does not have sufficient buffer or storage for you to write 70kb. What you need is to write in a loop, each write will write the amount that is left unwritten:

```
int total = body.length(); // or strlen(body.c_str())
char *buffer = body.c_str();
int written = 0;
int ret;
while (written < total) {
    ret = write(fd, buffer + written, total - written);
    if (ret < 0) {
        // error
        break;
    }
    written += ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your convincing explanation! It's very useful for me . I think I had find the solution for this problem :)